# R notebook loose images after a few days opened in Rstudio

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, rnotebook

I'm using Rstudio notebook to create nice Rmarkdown reports generated in html. Rstudio is opened during days on the same notebook, and sometimes all images disappear except those recently generated.
In the html, I see they are still existing, but it seem they are not correctly encoded, so probably impossible to read by Rstudio. Any suggestion ?

[image: Example of HTML page, heatmap have been generated a few hours ago, and the other figure days ago]